# Regular Expressions: Assertions

Tags: regex

I would like to know what the definition for an assertion is in the context of regular expressions. If anyone should know, please enlighten me with a brief definition of what it actually is. I would also appreciate one or two examples of such.

Answer (score 5):

#### What is a Regular Expression Assertion?

An Assertion is a Regular Expression that either succeeds (if a match is found) or fails (if a match is not found).

They consist of Anchors and Lookarounds.

---

#### Anchors

> An Anchor is a zero-width Assertion. They do not cause the engine to
>   advance through the string or consume characters, and can be one of
>   the following:
>
> - `^` - The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.
> - `$` - The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.
> - `\A` - The match must occur at the start of the string.
> - `\Z` - The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the string.
> - `\z` - The match must occur at the end of the string.
> - `\G` - The match must occur at the point where the previous match ended.
> - `\b` - The match must occur on a boundary between a `\w` (alphanumeric) and a `\W` (nonalphanumeric) character.
> - `\B` - The match must not occur on a `\b` boundary.

Source [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions)

---

#### Lookarounds

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called "lookaround", are
>   zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start
>   and end of word anchors.
>
> The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but
>   then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.
>   That is why they are called "assertions". They do not consume
>   characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible
>   or not.
>
> Lookaround allows you to create regular expressions that are
>   impossible to create without them, or that would get very longwinded
>   without them.

Source [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> [image]

Source [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)